# Angular JS Post is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, post, ionic-framework

I am using angularjs and ionic.I post multiple data from angular js to Api Controller in asp.net mvc

I have below code in order to **post multiple form data** to controller in asp.net mvc from angularjs.

```
  $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:51425/api/values/Response',
        params: { PropertyFirst: "1", PropertySecond: "2" },
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    }).success(function (data) {
        alert("ok");
    });
```

If i use below code this **works**

```
[HttpPost]
public object Response(string PropertyFirst , string PropertySecond)
{

HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");


return null;
}
```

However, if i use below code it is **not working**

**PropertyClass**

```
public string PropertyFirst{ get; set; }
public string PropertySecond{ get; set; }
```

**Controller side**

```
[HttpPost]
public object Response(PropertyClass propertyValues)
{

HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

return null;
}
```

I get below error :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

**Question:**

How can i post **PropertyFirst** and **PropertySecond** to **PropertyClass** ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is `PropertyClass` [annotated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: PropertyClass is name of class . I add properties in PropertyClass

Comment: Yes, but does it's declaration include the `[DataMember]` & `[DataContract]` attributes?

Comment: no nothing it is normal class

Comment: Do you have the server logs to figure out what the `500` is?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578814/how-to-receive-json-in-a-mvc-5-action-method-as-a-paramter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Angular $HTTP docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) :

params – {Object.} – Map of strings or objects which will be serialized with the paramSerializer and appended as **GET parameters.**

I don't know much about asp MVC framework, but if you **change the 'params' key to a 'data' key, your request will be correct**.

Unfortunately I can't really help with the ASP controllers, as I am entirely unfamiliar with that language.