# How to append a Collection in JQuery FormData Object

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, form-data

I've a collection of `Cards` in my `EmployeeMasterA` class, I'm not sure what is the correct way to append the collection in `FormData` object. What I want something like this :

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('Cards[0].CardId', 1);
data.append('Cards[0].CardTitle', "Credit");
data.append('Cards[1].CardId', 2);
data.append('Cards[1].CardTitle', "Debit");
```

and this is my ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/EmployeeMasterA/Create',        
    data: data,
    type: 'POST',        
    contentType: false,
    processData : false,        
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.Success == "1") {                
        }
    }
});
```

and my `controller` :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(EmployeeMasterA employeeMasterA)
{
    //get data and perform logics
}
```

`EmployeeMasterA` Class :

```
public class EmployeeMasterA
{
    public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Cards> Cards { get; set; }
}
```

`EmployeeMasterA` contains collection of Cards, here is the `Cards` Class :

```
public class Cards
{
    public int CardId { get; set; }
    public string CardTitle { get; set; }
}
```

How do I append the collection of `Cards` in the `FormData` object? So that it binds correctly with the `EmployeeMasterA` class.

**Update**

When I take a look in debug mode, the `Cards` collection is `null`, Why?

Comment: The code you have shown works perfectly and `Cards` contains 2 items that are correctly populated. If its not working for you, its either not the code your using or you have omitted some relevant code.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, You are right, I was doing a very silly mistake, `FormData` was getting reinitialized, that's why I was getting `null`, Thank you so much for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using FormData? You can simply send json object of your data.

See this: [How to receive JSON as an MVC 5 action method parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578814/how-to-receive-json-as-an-mvc-5-action-method-parameter)

Comment: I want to upload images along with the data, that is why I needed `FormData` because JSON does not allow.