# How do you post an object using ajax in asp.net?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Here is the product class:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Range(1, 1000000)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my .cshtml page:

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
    <span id="responseMessage"></span>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Price</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Price)
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Category</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Category)
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Description</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Description)
</div>
<button id="postButton">Ok</button>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#postButton").click(function () {
        var product = 'product=' +
            JSON.stringify({
                Name: $('#Name').val(),
                Description: $('#Description').val(),
                Price: $('#Price').val(),
                Category: $('#Category').val()
            });


        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/products/postproduct",
            type: "POST",
            data: product,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                $('#responseMessage').html('Insert status: ' + 
                data.d.status);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert('Error occurred: ' + status);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here is my controller:

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostProduct(Product product)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await Repository.SaveProductAsync(product);
            return Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance.  The ajax post hits the controller ( i set a breakpoint there), but when i hover over the product parameter there are no values coming in.  Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Have you tried leaving off the `'product='` part and just sending the object without the stringify?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21579294/3356508

Comment: If you are using .net core then make sure to add `[FromBody]` to the request model in the controller action.

Answer (score 0):

What I think your issue is:

You are passing data to your method but the parameter is not yet of type Product. You may need to change your parameter type to a more generic type of `object`. Then you could cast it to your desired `product` model.

Once data enters your controller, it expects a strongly-typed object of `product`. Thus, changing the parameter type to `object` allows you to parse every child of `object`.

Answer (score 0):

either change parameter name in controller to this
    public async Task PostProduct(Product Product)

Or change in jquery 
    data : {"product", product}

Hope this will works.