# How to receive a JSON body in C# MVC (no ajax)

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, restsharp

I have a client which is sending a json to my asp.net mvc application. Where can I receive the json body?

sending:

```
        var client = new RestClient(uri);
        client.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator();

        RestRequest requestCom =
            new RestRequest("", method);

        //add headers
        requestCom.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

        if (body != null)
        {
            requestCom.AddJsonBody(body);
        }

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(requestCom);
```

controller:

```
    public string Index([FromBody]object body)
    {
        return body.ToString();
    }
```

The url is my controller in the mvc application. So how can i receive the body?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to receive JSON as an MVC 5 action method parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578814/how-to-receive-json-as-an-mvc-5-action-method-parameter)

Comment: i dont want to use javascript and ajax, just c#

Comment: there is no model, i have just a string for testing. so for no we could also say: string body

Comment: Does that string represent a JSON object?

Comment: @mason yes, the string is now just: string body = "test";

Comment: @mason Actually it is valid JSON.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487869/is-this-simple-string-considered-valid-json).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say you have a model like this

```
public class MyModel {
    public string AProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And send to the server

```
var client = new RestClient(uri);
client.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator();

var requestCom = new RestRequest("", method);
//add headers
requestCom.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

var body = new MyModel {
    AProperty = "Hello World!!!"
}

if (body != null) {
    requestCom.AddJsonBody(body);
}

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(requestCom);
```

The Controller action would have to expect the model in the body

```
public string Index([FromBody]MyModel body) {
    return body.ToString();
}
```