# Not Able to pass Angular List (JsonList) to C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, model-view-controller

I know this has been asked a lot of times. But believe me I have tried them and this ain't working.

I have this simple List and Method :-

```
$scope.TblData = [];
        var Name='Name'; var Desc='Desc';
        $scope.TblData = [
            { Key: Name, Value: ClassSubjectName },
            { Key: Desc, Value: ClassSubjectDesc }
        ];
        InsertFactory.InsertClassSubject($scope.TblData).then(function (d) {
            alert(d.data + ' Subject Details');
        }, function (error) {
            alert('Cannot Save Contact Details');
        })
```

Which I'm getting at factory like :-

```
    BoardObj.InsertClassSubject = function (TblData) {
    var ViewID = 'ClassSubject';
    var Data = $.param({ TblList: ViewID, TblData: TblData });
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Admin/InsertTblData',
        data: JSON.stringify(Data),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
        }
    });
}
```

Trying to get it at server like this:-

```
if (Request.Form["TblData"] != null)
        {
            JsonData =  Request.Form["TblData"].ToString();
        }
        aBundleInsert.TblDataParams = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>(JsonData);
```

Ofcourse I'm doing it wrong but can't find the issue.

Comment: You're passing a JSON string but declaring the type as `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"` when the data isn't form encoded (it's JSON)?

Comment: Yes. So I need to change my Controller Code?

Comment: You need to either form encode your data, or declare that you're sending JSON. If declare that you're sending JSON, you need to change your controller code to accept the _model_ you're sending.

Comment: Thanks. Can you share a link or something as an example?

Comment: [Maybe this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578814/how-to-receive-json-as-an-mvc-5-action-method-parameter)

Answer (score 0):

You are not posting your data as form post.
`TblData` is a `scope` variable, it will not come inside your `Form` object, `Form` is meant for input elements only.

Ideally you should be posting the data to a `model` at the server side, but if you still want to access it on server side, you can try like following.

```
string postContent = "";
HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream, 
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true, 4096, true))
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        postContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```