# how to read form/data value in web api

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to `POST` `Json` data to `API` and read the value from the key using the `HttpContext.Current.Request` object.

**Client Side:**

```
var data = { Name: "Tom" };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (response) {

    }
    });
```

**In API:**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("UploadProduct")]
public HttpResponseMessage Upload()
{

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request["Name"]))
                return "Name is missing";

//... removed for brevity

}
```

Why key Name is always empty ?

I know `Json` data will bind to model object only. But like to know if it's possible to get data from `HttpContext.Current.Request` object by making some changes in client side ?

Comment: Why would you want to get the data from `HttpContext.Current.Request` when you can bind it to a model as parameter?

Comment: Does your `data` (as in `JSON.stringify(data)`) contain a 'Name' property?  You've not included it either way in the question.

Comment: @jom The API is already use with client , so dont want to break things. Also is there any way to read data apart from `HttpContext.Current.Request` ?

Comment: Can you post a sample of this data you are passing to the method?

Comment: @stom Also, why do you think model binding the data in the method breaks things?

Comment: Have you tried `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.AllKeys` to check what's actually being passed?  Have you checked the browser network tab to see what's being sent?

Comment: @jom added the sample data.

Comment: Do you need the `stringify` for any specific reason?  Try without this (and remove contentType): `$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: url, data: data, dataType: "json", success: ...`  With stringify you're only posting a single json value (it's not auto-expanded by web-api), not a form, so `Request["form-field-name"]` doesn't have a form to get the field name from.  This is handled when you use model-binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, try this:

Change `contentType` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, remove the `JSON.stringify()` and just pass the JSON data as is. With this you should be able to get the form values with `this.Request.Form["Name"]` or simply `this.Request["Name"]` or even `HttpContext.Current.Request["Name"]`.

When you `POST` data to server (particularly with content types other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`), the content is being placed in the `Request` body, and so it's not going to be available for reading in the [`Request.Form`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.form?view=netframework-4.7.2) name-value collection object.

For nested data, you can query the values just like you would with Javascript object literal, something like:

```
var data = {
  Name: "Tom",
  Address: {
    Street: "ABC"
  }
}
```

```cs
this.Request.Form["Address[Street]"] // ABC
```

Although it's always better to use model binding whenever possible.

Comment: Hi, can you review your sentence `so it's not going to be available for reading in the Request.Form`, I think it should be  `so it's going to be available for reading in the Request.Form`.

Comment: @stom When you post data as JSON for example, it should not go in `Request.Form`. If you need to post them as JSON, you could use model binding. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21579294/3634538) for example.